# is there a way to execute a function when I have its name in a string

Tags: javascript, reflection, parameters, eval

Consider I have a name of a function which does not require any argument in a var -

```
var fn = "foo";
```

Can I execute it in some or similar like this -

```
eval(fn);
```

It does not work. Please suggest.

My definition of function will look like this -

```
function foo() {
  ....do something....
}
```

Comment: There are other ways to decide on a function at runtime. Do you absolutely need the name in a string?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

try this

```
eval(fn)();
```

or this

```
eval(fn + "()");
```

Comment: eval is considered evil. It will work but is not necessary and should be avoided

Comment: @mplungjan, I guess I know you from EE days :). Anyways, eval is evil if the string to be evaluated is entered by user, otherwise it should be fine barring the fact that string will be compiled and then executed.

Comment: Sure - but it is better to never use it than to use it instead of a more appropriate method - and yes, we know each other ;)

Answer (score 1):

Please do not use eval.

If the function is in global scope, simply do

```
var fn = "foo";
window[fn]();
```

[DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/mplungjan/V3AXD/)